# ModelState Error c# mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

In an Action Result that does a HttpPost i get an error from EF

"ModelState.Errors Internal error in the expression evaluator"

My model in View is OrdineOmaggio

```
 public partial class OrdineOmaggio
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Id_Gioielleria { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Data_Ordine { get; set; } 
    public virtual Consumatore MD_CONSUMATORE { get; set; }
    public virtual Omaggio MD_OMAGGIO { get; set; }
    public virtual CodiceRandomConsumatore MD_RANDOM_CONSUMATORE { get; set; }
}
```

My Action is so

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ChooseGift(
            [Bind(Include ="Data_Ordine,MD_RANDOM_CONSUMATORE,MD_OMAGGIO,Id_Gioielleria")]
            OrdineOmaggio ordineOmaggio,
            string codiceOmaggio, string codice)
        {
            var randomConsumatore = _context.CodiciRandomConsumatori
                .SingleOrDefault(c => c.Codice == codice) ??
                                    new CodiceRandomConsumatore
                                    {
                                        Id = -1,
                                        Codice = "",
                                        Assegnato = null,
                                        Distinzione = ""
                                    };

            var consumatore = _context.CodiciRandomConsumatori
                .Where(c => c.Codice == codice)
                .Select(c => c.MD_CONSUMATORE)
                .SingleOrDefault();

            var omaggio = _context.Omaggi
                .SingleOrDefault(c => c.CodiceOmaggio == codiceOmaggio);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ordineOmaggio.Data_Ordine = DateTime.Now;
                ordineOmaggio.Id_Gioielleria = ordineOmaggio.Id_Gioielleria; 
                ordineOmaggio.MD_CONSUMATORE = consumatore; // FK
                ordineOmaggio.MD_OMAGGIO = omaggio; // FK
                ordineOmaggio.MD_RANDOM_CONSUMATORE = randomConsumatore; // FK

                _context.OrdiniOmaggio.Add(ordineOmaggio);

                randomConsumatore.Assegnato = true;

                _context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Success");
            }
            return View(ordineOmaggio);
        }
```

The error is about dataAnnotation: it say that not all field all filled

The metadata is

```
 public class OrdineOmaggioMetadata
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Scegli la gioiellereia.")]
    public string Id_Gioielleria;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Seleziona una foto.")]
    public Omaggio MD_OMAGGIO;

    ...
}
```

In my view i placed

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m=> m.MD_OMAGGIO.CodiceOmaggio)
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MD_OMAGGIO.CodiceOmaggio)
```

but this helper pass null to ActionResult

MD_OMAGGIO is a table foreign key for product codes.

what i wrong ?

Comment: `Omaggio` is another class? You need to have `Required` attribute on `CodiceOmaggio` property of `Omaggio`

Comment: You should explicitly expose the foreign key property to `MD_OMAGGIO` (presumably something like `Id _MD_OMAGGIO`) and use a `HiddenFor` for that property.

Comment: if i set an hiddenfor MD_OMAGGIO_Id then i receive a message: field Id is mandatory. Im near to solve? How can i set Id in my view ?

Comment: I pass the id with jquery to HiddenFor ...then var omaggio = _context.Omaggi
                .SingleOrDefault(c => c.CodiceOmaggio == ordineOmaggio.MD_OMAGGIO.CodiceOmaggio); seems works